# In a wordpress template, pass javascript result to a php function

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function

In the following template, I'd like to pass RESULT to the function programmatically_create_post(RESULT);

```
<?php
/*
 Template Name: Play
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 */
get_header();
$base = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/xxxxx';
?>
    <div ...
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base; ?>/css/xxxxx.css" />
    <script src="<?php echo $base; ?>/js/xxxxx.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $base; ?>/js/xxxxx.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="board" style="width: 400px"></div>
    <p>A: <span id="a"></span></p>
    <script>
        var init = function() {
            ...
  RESULT = $('#a'),
  ...
  RESULT.html(a);
};
            ...
        };
        jQuery(document).ready(init);

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // We'll pass this variable to the PHP function programmatically_create_post
            var fruit = 'Banana';
            // This does the ajax request
            $.ajax({
                //url: ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    'action':'programmatically_create_post',
                    'fruit' : fruit
                },
                success:function(data) {
                    // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
            <?php
            ...
        $post_id = programmatically_create_post(RESULT);
        ...
```

RESULT is a string returned by a javascript.

"A:" RESULT is displayed.

When I do `$post_id = programmatically_create_post("essai");` it is working, the post is created with "essai".

How can I send RESULT to the programmatically_create_post function ?

Comment: There are generally only three ways to do this not counting the HTTP methods people rarely use. $_GET(vars send via the url), $_POST(vars sent via a form or $_SESSION( People use sessions when the data should be persistent for well.. a session. So without looking I would say after you get the result via your js function. Append it to the url as a GET var or send it as a post var via a hidden form field and a form that is auto submitted when the js call is finished.

Comment: PHP is processed server side before the code is sent to the client browser.  Javascript is run client side in the browser.  So, when the javascript is executed, it's too late to change the php code.  The only way around this is an ajax request.

Comment: Thank you, I've seen many post to pass php variable to javascript but not in the other way. Do you have some tutorial about this ?

Comment: I've read few tutorials, please see my edited code. I got the following stack in the console : Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxurl is not defined  I've seen that I need to add  `code wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );` but it's not working

Comment: I make the ajax url working but I can't pass the RESULT to the data (fruit). I'd like `data'{ 'fruit' : RESULT}` but I get `[fruit] =>  `